# Getting currently selected parameter from executionEvent when handler is called

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I could not find anything about this on the web so I decided to ask here.
I declared a handler for a command in my rcp plugin.xml.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
 <command 
  categoryId="test.category.id"
  id="com.test.Handler"
  defaultHandler="com.test.Handler"
  name="Create Zip" >
   <commandParameter
    id="com.param.Params"
    name="zip"
    values="com.param.Params">
   </commandParameter>
 </command>
</extension>
```

And I added the classes to my Project. The handler implements the method `AbstractHandler.execute(ExecutionEvent event)` and the parameters represent the different options I want to invoke `FormatActionParameters.getParameterValues()`. If a shortcut is pressed the event is fire.

But when it is fired I cannot determine which parameter was used in the handler. The ExecutionEvent only has the complete list of parameters and does not only contains the selected one.

My problem is: How can I track where the command was coming from. I need to know what was selected.

Comment: Not something I use but looking at various Eclipse internal handlers they all seem to just call `ExecutionEvent.getParameter(id)`

Answer (score 0):

First I thought, that the call of `event.getParameter("my.key.from.the.plugin")` would give me the whole command with all keys. While debugging I've seen that this call will give me the parameter I need.